# std::initializer_list conversion in constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I'm new to C++11 and I was wondering how this code works internally:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(int a, double b) {
            cout << "ctor()" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass i1{4, 7};
    return 0;
}
```

My understanding of the new initializer list is that it is a class `std::initializer_list` constructed by special syntax `{ .... }` in the code. So how does this class instance created by `{4, 7}` internally get transformed to a form that fits the constructor to `MyClass`? Thanks.

Comment: The syntax `{....}` *can* construct a `std::initializer_list`... or it can do other things.

Comment: @immibis Is there a good reference on this I can read?

Comment: Maybe refer to Item 6 of "Effective Modern C++"

Comment: @hovo [Here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init) you can find the details about initializers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is how it happens. Extracted from: [Explanation of list initialization at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

> If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all)